# find a string on a spreadsheet is behaving odd google app script

Tags: logging, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17MopjIBa1PRCenf9C0J7bXQYdie5BMNJHegTDyefQcw/edit?usp=sharing) spreadsheet, and searching for the the row and column in which a certain string in it, using the following code:

```
function test(){
var searchFor ="theFilename";  
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor); 
  var file = files.next();  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var array = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  // file date
  var searchString = 'Listado';         
  var RC = getColumn(array,searchString);
  var Column = RC.Column;
  var Row = RC.Row-1;
  var date = array[Row,Column].toString();
  Logger.log(Row+':'+Column+':'+date);      
}
function getColumn(array,searchString){
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {        
    for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {          
      if (array[i][j].toString().indexOf(searchString)>-1) {
        Logger.log(i+':'+j+':'+array[i][j].toString());
        var Row = i+1;
        var Column = j;
        return {Row: Row, Column: Column};
      }      
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

The problem is that in Logger.log line in getColumn function shows what is is expected `2:3:Listado de Licitaciones Publicadas al 05/10/2017 07:12`, but the Logger.log line in test function, that should show the same as the other, it shows `2:3:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,` instead...

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [array index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Multi-dimensional_arrays) for `[row, column]` value would be `array[][]`

```
// Change the array index of date to
var date = array[Row][Column].toString();
```

Comment: That's so right. I guess coding when tired isn't very productive...  thanks